# why does my array.join() not work as expected?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, join, safari

Safari 6:

```
> ['a=23', 'b=234', 'c=23'].join('&');
"a=23&b=234&c=23"
```

then with a variable I need to do this with. it's

```
jsss
  [
  Array[8]
    0: "s=1"
    1: "l=NTA4NTQzNnw0NzczOTg"
    2: "r=-1"
    3: "t=a"
    4: "m=0"
    5: "si=5156695"
    6: "u=5085436"
    7: "sn=mip"
    length: 8
    __proto__: Array[0]
   ]

> jsss.join('&');
"s=1,l=NTA4NTQzNnw0NzczOTg,r=-1,t=a,m=0,si=5156695,u=5085436,sn=mip"
```

Why does it seem to ignore the separator?

Comment: awesome. I've been out of this for a year and need to get back up to speed... thanks to both answerers here.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It looks like you have an array with a nested array, so you're only calling join on the top array which only has one element (the child array) and therefore just echoes that array with default behavior and nothing to delimit.

Answer (score 6):

There is only one item in the `jsss` array so there is no use for the separator. I think what you want is `jsss[0].join('&');`

Comment: This one worked for me after frantically searching. Thank you.